# Correct way to append a noun to a action

Tags: particle-を, particle-で

What is the correct way to append a noun to a action. For example

> 書き**で**頑張ります 
>   書き**を**頑張ります

I think both the above means "I will do my best at writing". In the example above, the stem of a verb is a noun.

Example 2:

> 親切**で**有難う 
>   親切**を**有難う

Are both particles acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

'親切**で**有難う' is wrong.

'親切**を**有難う' is acceptable, but '親切にしてくれてありがとう' is much more natural.

More politely:

- 親切にしてくださりありがとうございます。

More formally (e.g. in a letter):

- （貴殿の / 皆様の）ご親切に感謝申し上げます。

Comment: I don't think 親切で有難う is wrong.

Comment: So using に particle is the correct way? For example: 新設に有難う？Similarly, for stem of verbs (書き、聞き、磨き、など), using に is correct? For example: 磨きに頑張ります ?

Comment: @Ben 親切で有難う is definitely wrong.

Comment: You can say it's wrong but Japanese people are using this: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%A6%AA%E5%88%87%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%22

Comment: @donburi You cannot say 磨きに頑張る nor 親切に有難う. 磨きを頑張ります is acceptable, but 頑張って磨きます is much more natural. 磨きに注力/専念する is OK too (although the meaning is not the same as 頑張る). を for 頑張る and に for 注力する are collocations of the verbs. Particles are not decided by nouns. By the way, 親切 is not the stem of a verb.

Comment: @Ben No, grammatically wrong. 皆さん親切でありがたかったです is alright. Even Japanese people make mistakes in Japanese. Or they may not be Japanese. Just because there are fairly amount of search results doesn't always mean it's correct.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that 親切でありがとう is not a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to 磨き as the stem of verb. 頑張って磨きます sounds like "I will do my best and polish" rather than "I will do my best to polish"

Comment: @donburi Isn't it almost the same? It is to polish that the person does his/her best for in 頑張って磨きます. The difference is not there but in that 磨きを頑張ります implies that the person does polishing especially among several actions, whereas 頑張って磨きます does not have such implication. What are you going to polish? If you want to polish yourself to improve, you can use other expressions like 己の鍛錬に努めます/励みます. 磨きを頑張る does not sound so natural anyway.

Comment: Fair statement. I'll accept the answer with a couple more upvotes, just in case